# why to link the an outlet to the ViewController as a delegate or a data-source

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am following [image: this tutorial] and as shown in image-1 below, I had to link the delegate and dataSource of the outlet "TableView" to ViewController.

Can you please explain the following:

1- why do I need to link UITableView "Outlet" with the dataSource of the ViewController, and to delegate the ViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no sure whether I understood you correctly. 
You need to connect TableView with View Controller which it belongs to because using Table View `dataSource` methods you will provide objects to display in Table View and you will customize cells, by `delegate` you will be able e.g. to receive touches for particular cell in view controller.

Another way to connect your TableView with ViewController is to simply create tableView `outlet` in View Controller and then link those properties 
in VC e.g.:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

See also this useful article:
https://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/

Comment: when i link the outlet to the viewocontroller as a delegate...in such case, is the ViewController is the delegate of the outlet"UITableView" or the outlet is the delegate of "ViewController"..IMHO, i think it it should be that outlet is the delegate of ViewController, in the sense of, UITableView will receive the touches and , then the touches will be sent to ViewController to  process it....right?

Answer (score 0):

Probably You can set tableView delegate & datesource to viewController via programmatically like below

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

as well as You can set same-thing in view part to linking delegate and dataSource of the outlet "TableView" to ViewController like your image.

Comment: thank you for your your answer..but my question was why do I need to link them

Comment: @user2121 I didn't get you exactly. Are you asking whether use of data source & delegate linking to viewController either programmatically or interface builder? or why do i need to link in view part only?

Comment: the 2nd part of your quest.

Comment: @user2121 because you need to connect them to show your data & handling actions with help of both protocols.Connecting via view part is Optional.You can do it in your swift file too.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: These are two protocols of UITableView through which your UITableView communicate with its boss (here will be your UIViewController). So to communicate with each other both of them needs references of each other. UIViewController have a reference to the table in the form of UITableView object but UITableView have no reference of its boss. Through the DataSource Protocol the boss (UIViewController) order to the UITableView how many cells to display and what to display on these cells, and through the Delegate Protocol UITableView notifies its boss that i done with my work when some actions are performed.

So Thats why UITableView both protocols needs its boss reference which we provide in case of:

```
 tableView.delegate = self
 tableView.dataSource = self
```

or from Storyboard or NIb.